# Can I mix in javascript modules with "regular" javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a page setup which references a couple of javascript files and has some javascript inline in the page, which is generated when the page is loaded.

One of the javascript files contains a class from a third-party library.

The other javascript file contains various variables, event handlers and functions relating to the page, which use the class from the third-party library (`var v = new thirdPartyClass(parameters);`).

The third party has recently updated their library and switched to using modules, so now instead of having a class available, they have a class export available. This is my first exposure to js modules.

So now instead of including the js file, as I understand it, I have to import the class from the module. When I try that, I get a console error that only modules can import. I added `type="module"` to the `<script>` tag for my js file (it was already added to the third party js script tag) and then I could import their class, but now my functions can't be accessed from the page (`function Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`). I don't know if events work because it doesn't get that far any more.

Is there any way I can use their new exported class without having to completely restructure my js file to be a module and change the page to work with it?

Comment: It seems the easiest solution would be to transpile their module into a regular script that puts the export in a global variable, e.g. UMD format. Then just use that and you don't have to change anything else.

Comment: @Bergi - Do you have any recommendations for tutorials on how to do that please? This is all new to me, I'm mostly a backend developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create global variables in modules using `var`. To access the function you can export it out of the file:

```js
export myFunction;
```

and import it into the file you need it in:

```js
import {myFunction} from "./relativeFilePath";
```

Or if you want to create a global variable from within the module you can put the variable directly into the `window` object:

```js
window.myFunction = function() {
  //code
};
```

Comment: Using `window.myFunction` is useful to know, but this still means I have to put all my variables somewhere else and do this with all of the functions that are referenced in other places and re-test everything. I was hoping that there was a way to more simply replace `var v = new thirdPartyClass(parameters)` without having to make changes all over the place.

Comment: If you want `v` to be global just change it to `window.v = new thirdPartyClass(parameters);`

Comment: The problem isn't `v` by itself, the problem is that there are many functions and variables that are in my js file and I was hoping to avoid turning it into a module if possible. The thing is, if it's not a module, I can't figure out how to use `thirdPartyClass` from in that js file.

Comment: You can use a module file to create `v` and make it global, then inlude the regular scripts. Not all scripts have to be modules.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a script type module, import the objects desired and put them in a window.{the name of your obj} as:

```
<script type="module">
    import { theItem } from "/path/to/module.js";
    window.theItem = theItem;
</script>
```

The remaining code can be in regular js.

Answer (score 0):

> So now instead of including the js file, as I understand it, I have to import the class from the module. When I try that, I get a console error that only modules can import.

That's true for conventional, static `import` statements.

But, significantly, the dynamic `import()` operator (an alternative, aynschronous way to import modules) may be used to import modules into classic javascript files as well as into other modules.

**MDN** notes:

> The `import()` syntax, commonly called **dynamic import**, is a function-like expression that allows loading an ECMAScript module asynchronously and dynamically into *a potentially non-module environment* [...]

and:

> [...] you might need to use dynamic import:
>
> - When you are in a *non-module environment* (for example [...] *a script file*).

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

---

**Example:**

```
// /my-classic-javascript-file.js

const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  const { myImportedClass } = await import('/path/to/module.js');
}
```

---

### Further Reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Answer (score 0):

A `window` property setter solution:

```html
<script type="module">
   import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js';                 
   alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
   window.Dms = Dms;
</script>

<script>
  let Dms;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'Dms', {
    get(){
      return Dms;
    },
    set(val){
      Dms = val;
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('dms-set'));
    }
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('dms-set', () => alert('SECOND TIME: ' + Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms')));
  
</script>
```

Some promise solution:

```html
<script type="module">
   import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js';                 
   alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
   window.Dms = Dms;
</script>

<script>

  promisifyGlobal('Dms');
  
  Dms.then(Dms => alert('SECOND TIME: ' + Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms')));

  function promisifyGlobal(name){
    let global, promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      Object.defineProperty(window, name, {
        get(){
          return promise;
        },
        set(val){
          global = val;
          resolve(global);
        }
      });
    });
  }

</script>
```

You can easily import dynamically into a non-module script:

```html
<script>

  (async () => {
    
    const {default: Dms} = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js');
    alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));
  
  })();

</script>
```

And finally some crazy generic solution:

```html
<script type="module">

  import Dms from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.4.0/dms.js'; 
  alert(Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms'));

</script>

<script>

  // this script will handle all imports 
  // tweak to import several exports and named exports

  for(const script of document.querySelectorAll('script[type=module]')) {
    
    const regex = /import\s+([^\s]+)\s+from\s+["\']([^"\']+)/g;
    let matches;
    while(matches = regex.exec(script.textContent)){
      const [, name, url] = matches;
      const src = `import ${name} from '${url}'; export default ${name};`;
      window[name] = new Promise(resolve => {
        import(`data:text/javascript, ${src}`).then(({default:imported}) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(imported));
        });
      });
    }

  }

</script>

<script>

  Dms.then(Dms => alert('SECOND TIME: ' + Dms.toLat(-3.62, 'dms')));

</script>
```